# MySQL set data type when AS expression is used

Tags: mysql, types, casting

I need to set a data type to a field but I can't get it done:

```
SELECT fname,lname,tname,games,
IFNULL((ib+iib+iiib+hr),0) AS h int (6), [does't work]
IFNULL((a+b+c)),0.000) AS ops decimal (6,3) [does't work]
FROM players,stats,teams
WHERE players.playerID = stats.sid AND players.club=teams.tid
ORDER BY obp DESC
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html (Didn't downvited BTW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the value beforehand:

```
SELECT fname, lname, tname, games,
       CAST(COALESCE(ib+iib+iiib+hr, 0) as signed) AS h, 
       CAST(COALESCE(a+b+c, 0.000)  as decimal(6, 3)) AS ops 
FROM players p JOIN
     stats s
     ON p.playerID = s.sid JOIN
     teams t
     ON p.club = t.tid
ORDER BY obp DESC;
```

I don't think length parameters for integers are permitted in `cast()`/`convert()`.

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Use table aliases and qualified column names, *always* when your query refers to more than one table.
- I prefer `COALESCE()` to `IFNULL()` because `COALESCE()` is standard SQL.
- I am highly suspicious of this join condition:  `p.playerID = s.sid`.

Comment: Done, exactly what I was looking for! Thx very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use COALESCE function is MySQL.

Example:

```
SELECT COALESCE(null, 0)
```

So your query (assuming column name can have right values not to typecast any datatype any more) can look like below.

```
SELECT COALESCE ((ib+iib+iiib+hr),0) AS h,  COALESCE ((a+b+c),0.000) AS ops 
FROM players,stats,teams WHERE players.playerID = stats.sid 
AND players.club=teams.tid ORDER BY obp DESC;
```

Just try this, in absence of data I've just provided you a sample query.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is just a easy MySQL connection to admin the Baseball stats of my team mates.

```
SELECT fname,lname,tname,games,
CAST(coalesce(ib+iib+iiib+hr,0) as signed) AS h,r,
CAST(coalesce(ib+iib+iiib+hr+so+fc+o,0) as signed) AS 
ab1,iib,iiib,hr,rbi,bb,
CAST(coalesce((ib*1)+(iib*2)+(iiib*3)+(hr*4),0) as signed) AS tb1,so,sb,
CAST(coalesce(((ib+iib+iiib+hr)+bb+hp)/(((ib+iib+iiib+hr)+so+fc+o)+bb+sf+hp)
,0.000) as decimal(6,3)) AS obp,
CAST(coalesce(((ib*1)+(iib*2)+(iiib*3)+
(hr*4))/((ib+iib+iiib+hr)+so+fc+o),0.000) as decimal(6,3)) AS slg,
CAST(coalesce((ib+iib+iiib+hr)/(((ib+iib+iiib+hr)+so+fc+o)),0.000) as 
decimal(6,3)) AS avg,
CAST(coalesce((((ib+iib+iiib+hr)+bb+hp)/(((ib+iib+iiib+hr)+so+fc+o)
+bb+sf+hp))+(((ib*1)+(iib*2)+(iiib*3)+
(hr*4))/((ib+iib+iiib+hr)+so+fc+o)),0.000) as decimal(6,3)) AS ops
FROM players p JOIN
 stats s
 ON p.playerID = s.sid JOIN
 teams t
 ON p.club=t.tid
ORDER BY obp DESC
```

Perfect exactly what I was looking for!